# How do I convert an array object to a string object in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, certificate, private-key

While trying to create an CSV file with information about certificates I have an issue to store the userrights on the private key.

The problem is that I want to store multiple values in one attribute so I use an array. 
At first I had no errors, however the column in my csv-file remained empty even in the case where the array has a value.

With a simple Write-Host I can see my array has the expected value so this part works okay.

For further investigations I have added the line:

```
Get-Member $certs.GetValue("UserRights")
```

This gives an error indicating I have to convert my variable to a string-variable.

[image]

So next I have tried to convert this array to a single string.
I have tried several ways but my error doesn't disappear so it doesn't work.
Underneath is my full code with some former attempts commented.

```
cls $certs = Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine -Recurse  | Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} | Select * Write-Host ("There were {0} certificates" -f ($certs | Measure-Object).Count)

foreach($certificate in $certs) {
    if($certificate.HasPrivateKey)
    {
        Write-Host "Certificate's PSChildName is" $certificate.PSChildName
        $rsaFile = $certificate.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
        $fullPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\" + $rsaFile
        $acl = Get-Acl -Path $fullPath
        foreach($accessrule in $acl.Access)
        {
            Write-Host "User" $accessrule.IdentityReference "has the following rights:" $accessrule.FileSystemRights
        }

        Write-Host "------"

        $UserRechten = @()

         foreach($accessrule in $acl.Access)
        {
         $UserRechten += "{0}:{1};" -f ($accessrule.IdentityReference,$accessrule.FileSystemRights)
        }  



        Write-Host "================================================================"


        # -join $UserRechten
        # $Userrechten | out-string
        # $UserRechten = [system.String]::Join(" ", $UserRechten)
        $separator = ";"
        [string]::Join($separator,$UserRechten)

        $certs | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UserRights" -Value $UserRechten -Force

        Write-Host "UserRechten has value : "$UserRechten

        Get-Member $certs.GetValue("UserRights")

        Write-Host "================================================================"


    } } 


$Certs | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MachineName" -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME -Force
# $certs | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Store" -Value 'My' -Force $RunDate = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd' $certs | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "RunDate" -Value $RunDate -Force $certs | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Owner" -Value $env:USERNAME -Force

$Certs | Select * | Export-Csv c:\Certificaten\LocalCertsAll_$env:COMPUTERNAME.csv 
$Certs | Select MachineName, Owner, PSParentPath, DnsNameList, PSChildName, NotBefore, NotAfter, Rundate, EnhancedKeyUsageList, HasPrivateKey, SerialNumber, Issuer, Subject, FriendlyName, UserRigthts | 
    Export-CSV c:\Certificaten\Localcerts_$env:COMPUTERNAME.csv
```

Comment: `GetValue` is an index accessor, `$certs.GetValue(0)` is the same as `$certs[0]`. What are you trying to accomplish with `Get-Member $certs.GetValue('UserRights')`?

Comment: maybe try just 'Get-Member $certs.UserRights'

Comment: If you want to save the data members of either just the user rights, the private key container, or the whole cert in a CSV file, then you definitely don't want `get-member`. `gm` gives info about the type of the argument which isn't needed if you already know what you're saving. It's not clear what is failing. Could you update you post & provide the info, particularly error messages? Finally if you initialize `$UserRechten` as an empty string, then your foreach loop will provide a concatenated string of the user right and you won't need the `-join` code.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, `Get-Member` is probably not what you're looking for

You (almost certainly) don't want to add the `UserRights` member property to the `$Certs` array, but rather to the individual objects in `$Certs`.

(I removed a bunch of superfluous `Write-Host` statements for readability):

```
$CertsAmended = foreach($Certificate in $certs)
{
    if($certificate.HasPrivateKey)
    {
        $rsaFile = $certificate.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName
        $fullPath = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\" + $rsaFile
        $acl = Get-Acl -Path $fullPath

        # Create the UserRights value using -join
        $UserRechten = @(foreach($accessrule in $acl.Access){
            Write-Host "User" $accessrule.IdentityReference "has the following rights:" $accessrule.FileSystemRights
            "{0}:{1}" -f ($accessrule.IdentityReference,$accessrule.FileSystemRights)
        }) -join ";"

        # Add the property to the individual object
        $Certificate | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UserRights" -Value $UserRechten

        Write-Host "Userrights: " $UserRechten

        # "Drop" the certificate object (now with a UserRights value) back onto the pipeline
        $Certificate
    } 
}
```

Now you can export the `$CertsAmended` array to CSV all you want

---

If you find the `$var = @(foreach($item in $collection){}) -join ';'` displeasing to the eye, break it into two statements:

```
$UserRechten = foreach($accessrule in $acl.Access)
{
    # Create UserRight string here, without ;
}
$UserRechten = $UserRechten -join ';'
```

---

For the `$fullPath` variable, you may want to use the `Join-Path` cmdlet:

```
$fullPath = Join-Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\" $rsaFile
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.
The only strange thing is that the command Get-Member $certs.UserRights gives no result.:
Property 'UserRights' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.

Comment: Because it doesn't. It exists as a property on each of the objects *inside* `$certs`, but not on `$certs` itself. Try `$certs | Get-Member -Name UserRights`